# Woocommerce add shortcode to front-end product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have been learning on how to make a plugin for Wordpress.
Now I am stumbling upon a "problem".
Which is: I need to add my shortcode to the product page of **Woocommerce**.

I have this function which makes my shortcode:

```
function ws_frontend_product_page_validate() {

    // no actual validation yet
    $output = ws_frontend_product_page();
    return $output;

}
add_shortcode('ws_frame', 'ws_frontend_product_page_validate');
function ws_frontend_product_page() {

    ?>

        <iframe src="http://www.example.com/" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0"></iframe>

    <?php

}
```

So how can I add `[ws_frame]` to the Woocommerce product pages?
I haven't found any tutorials as of how I can implement this into Woocommerce product pages.
I have found it very difficult to find the tutorials that I need to develope a plugin for Woocommerce. 
Any suggested tutorials would be very nice!

**UPDATE**

Now I have got an answer of Piyush Dhanotiya. I have yet to get the position right.

If I use the code of Piyush Dhanotiya it shows up as this:

[image]

Yet, I want it here:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_shortcode('ws_frame', 'ws_frontend_product_page_validate');
function ws_frontend_product_page_validate() {

   echo '<iframe src="http://www.example.com/" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0"></iframe>';

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'action_woocommerce_after_main_content', 10);

function action_woocommerce_after_main_content(){


    do_shortcode('[ws_frame]');
}
```

Comment: Nice, thank you. But do you have any idea as to how I can use this shortcode on product pages of Woocommerce?

Comment: you want to add this shortcode on all products right???

or you want to use it on single product page???

Comment: Yes, well atleast for now, later on I will make it more specific. Because it needs to be added to products in a certain category.

Comment: goto to the woocommerce/templates  and then add it in single-product.php file

Comment: Is there any way to do this on plugin activation? That it adds the shortcode to single-product.php automatically?

Comment: you can add your shortcode on this action this action is for perticular single page in woocomerce

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10 );

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105353/discussion-between-piyush-dhanotiya-and-sj03rs).

Comment: You do lead me in to the right direction. But I haven't still found out how to add the shortcode to all woocommerce product pages. How does `add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'action_woocommerce_after_main_content', 10);` know that it needs to add my shortcode to all woocommerce product pages?

Comment: see above i have updated my answer you can create shortcode then add that action inside this action function you can use do shortcode funvction to echo the content of that shortcode thats it....

Comment: Holy **** Thank you! That did it for me!

Comment: Hey I have one last question. How can I position the shortcode? As it shows up at the bottom of the product container div. I have already tried to use before_main_content. Any suggestions?

Comment: use ob_start();
or ob_flush();
if it is always showing in footer

Comment: It is not showing in the footer though. I will update my question to show you what I mean. Thanks for still helping me though! :D